# Adding median into all combinations of data using R package dpylr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

Here is my data

```
## Data
datex <- c(rep("2021-01-18", 61), rep("2021-01-19", 125))
hourx <- c(0,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,16,10,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16)
seller <- c("dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2")
product <- c("00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460")
detail <- c("E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","notEnoughBalance","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","notEnoughBalance","E99","success","success","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","E99","success","success","notEnoughBalance","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","notEnoughBalance","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","notEnoughBalance","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","success","E99")
status <- c("FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK01","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK01","FI04","OK00","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","OK01","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK01","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK01","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04")
channel <- c("f2","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2")
transaction <- c(1,6,2,5,1,2,1,9,6,12,5,25,14,6,22,9,10,14,15,12,22,12,12,14,9,11,3,3,4,0,1,4,3,1,2,3,3,5,7,5,5,6,9,16,8,13,10,20,15,18,10,19,15,5,13,12,10,12,26,14,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,4,0,6,8,0,2,3,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,1,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,6,5,2,0,8,0,0,12,11,0,2,0,11,0,0,14,21,0,0,13,7,0,17,0,0,18,0,7,0,4,4,0,0,7,12,0,13,0,0,13,6,9,0,0,0,16,0,0,16,0,14,0,0,9,0,11,8,0,8,0,0,8,0,10,5,0,15,0,0,3,0,0,8,8,0,0,6,5,0,8,0,0,5,1,0,0,3)
mydata <- data.frame(datex, hourx, seller, product, detail, status, channel, transaction)
```

My task is to add median into combination.
This is what i mean. It's a sample:

- seller = "dombsdpapp1"
- product = "00021460"
- detail = "E99"
- status = "FI04"
- channel = "f2"

```
combination1 <- mydata[(mydata$seller == "dombsdpapp1" & mydata$product == "00021460" & mydata$detail == "E99" & mydata$status == "FI04" & mydata$channel == "f2"),]

combination1
# datex hourx      seller  product detail status channel transaction
# 1   2021-01-18     0 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
# 2   2021-01-18     1 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
# 3   2021-01-18     2 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           2
# 5   2021-01-18     3 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
# 7   2021-01-18     4 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
# 9   2021-01-18     5 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
# 11  2021-01-18     6 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           5
# 13  2021-01-18     7 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          14
# 14  2021-01-18     8 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
# 16  2021-01-18     9 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           9
# 18  2021-01-18    10 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          14
# 20  2021-01-18    11 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          12
# 22  2021-01-18    12 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          12
# 25  2021-01-18    13 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           9
# 27  2021-01-18    14 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
# 28  2021-01-18    15 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
# 29  2021-01-18    16 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           4
# 71  2021-01-19     1 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           4
# 77  2021-01-19     2 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
# 85  2021-01-19     3 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           2
# 90  2021-01-19     4 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
# 97  2021-01-19     5 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
# 104 2021-01-19     6 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
# 112 2021-01-19     7 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          11
# 120 2021-01-19     8 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           7
# 130 2021-01-19     9 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           4
# 139 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          13
# 145 2021-01-19    11 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          16
# 156 2021-01-19    12 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
# 164 2021-01-19    13 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           5
# 173 2021-01-19    14 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
# 179 2021-01-19    15 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
# 183 2021-01-19    16 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
```

From the result, we can see datex "2021-01-18" and "2021-01-19" miss hourx from 17 to 23, So we need to add median of combination1 into hourx 17-23. i Do it manually like this

```
## Add Median into combination1
add_datex1 <- rep("2021-01-18",7); add_datex2 <- rep("2021-01-19",7); add_hourx <- 17:23; add_seller <- rep("dombsdpapp1",7); add_product <- rep("00021460",7); add_detail <- rep("E99",7); add_status <- rep("FI04",7); add_channel <- rep("f2",7); add_transaction <- rep(median(combination1$transaction),7)
add_18 <- data.frame(add_datex1, add_hourx, add_seller, add_product, add_detail, add_status, add_channel, add_transaction)
colnames(add_18) <- colnames(mydata)
add_19 <- data.frame(add_datex2, add_hourx, add_seller, add_product, add_detail, add_status, add_channel, add_transaction)
colnames(add_19) <- colnames(mydata)
new_combination1 <- rbind(combination1[1:17,],add_18, combination1[-(1:17),], add_19)
rownames(new_combination1) <- 1:47
```

```
new_combination1
        datex hourx      seller  product detail status channel transaction
#1  2021-01-18     0 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
#2  2021-01-18     1 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#3  2021-01-18     2 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           2
#4  2021-01-18     3 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
#5  2021-01-18     4 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
#6  2021-01-18     5 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#7  2021-01-18     6 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           5
#8  2021-01-18     7 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          14
#9  2021-01-18     8 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#10 2021-01-18     9 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           9
#11 2021-01-18    10 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          14
#12 2021-01-18    11 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          12
#13 2021-01-18    12 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          12
#14 2021-01-18    13 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           9
#15 2021-01-18    14 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
#16 2021-01-18    15 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
#17 2021-01-18    16 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           4
#18 2021-01-18    17 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#19 2021-01-18    18 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#20 2021-01-18    19 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#21 2021-01-18    20 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#22 2021-01-18    21 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#23 2021-01-18    22 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#24 2021-01-18    23 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#25 2021-01-19     1 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           4
#26 2021-01-19     2 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
#27 2021-01-19     3 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           2
#28 2021-01-19     4 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
#29 2021-01-19     5 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           3
#30 2021-01-19     6 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
#31 2021-01-19     7 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          11
#32 2021-01-19     8 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           7
#33 2021-01-19     9 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           4
#34 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          13
#35 2021-01-19    11 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          16
#36 2021-01-19    12 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
#37 2021-01-19    13 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           5
#38 2021-01-19    14 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
#39 2021-01-19    15 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           8
#40 2021-01-19    16 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           1
#41 2021-01-19    17 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#42 2021-01-19    18 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#43 2021-01-19    19 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#44 2021-01-19    20 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#45 2021-01-19    21 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#46 2021-01-19    22 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
#47 2021-01-19    23 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2           6
```

How do i add median into missing "hourx" automatically using dplyr for all combination?
Many Thank You.

Comment: why row for 0 hour in desired output for second group is missing?  Is that a typo, or you require to fill hours in between only.  In that case, I'll change my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function to complete `hourx` and fill it with `median`:

```
fillHour <- function(df){
  
  data.frame(
    hourx = 0:23
  ) %>%
    left_join(df, by = "hourx") %>%
    replace_na(list(transaction = median(.[["transaction"]], na.rm = TRUE)))
}
```

`nest` data frame and use `fillHour` on `data`:

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(datex, seller, product, detail, status, channel) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, fillHour)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = "data") %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need both `NA imputation` and `complete`.  Below strategy is suggested-

- group_by on all desired grouping variables at once (because you'll need these anyways while NA imputation)
- use `tidyr::complete` for completing 0:23 sequence of hourx for each of the group.
- use `coalesce` for NA imputation lastly

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% group_by(datex, seller, product, detail, status, channel) %>%
  complete(hourx = 0:23) %>%
  mutate(transaction = coalesce(transaction, median(transaction, na.rm = T)))
# A tibble: 408 x 8
# Groups:   datex, seller, product, detail, status, channel [17]
   datex      seller      product  detail status channel hourx transaction
   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          0          12
 2 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          1          12
 3 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          2          12
 4 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          3           5
 5 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          4           2
 6 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          5           9
 7 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          6          12
 8 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          7          25
 9 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          8          22
10 2021-01-18 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99    FI04   f3          9          10
# ... with 398 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hai bro.. the median that i use is not median of all transaction, but median of each combination. for the sample that i use, the median is 6, but the other combination will produce a different median. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba, See edited answer now.  Perhaps fill argument of `complete` isn't taking functions :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using dplyr to determine the median for each group, then lubridate to combine date and hour into a single field, and padr to fill in all the missing hour rows, and finally a join & coalesce to add the median for those missing rows.

```
library(padr); library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
medians <- mydata %>%
  group_by(seller, product, detail, status, channel) %>%
  summarise(median = median(transaction), .groups = "drop") 

mydata %>%
  mutate(timestamp =  lubridate::ymd_h(paste(datex, hourx))) %>%
  padr::pad(by = "timestamp", 
            group = c("seller", "product", "detail", "status", "channel")) %>%
  left_join(medians) %>%
  mutate(filled_transaction = coalesce(transaction, median))
```

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for answer, but i get so many NAs data in datex, hourx and some columns. I need to add median into missing hourx, not to make new columns . Thanks bro.

Comment: I added the columns to show the technique, you can replace the last line with `transaction = coalesce(transaction, median)` to get the answer there. And you can generare datex and hourx from the timestamp column, eg. `mutate(datex = ymd(timestamp), hourx = hour(timestamp))`

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for the answer, i am still new in dplyr package. for filling median is solved but to add datex and hourx, i still don't get the answer. can you write it bro? . Thanks Bro.